# How to call the_time current?

Tags: theme-development, functions, date-time

I'm using the_time function to print the current date on my site. The problem is, that it's returning post or page creation times on pages other than the front page.

Can I force it to print the *current* time on all views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the_time() function is a WordPress built-in function to display the time of the post creation.

So if you want to display the current date and time you need to use php function [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
something like this:

```
    <?php
// Assuming today is March 10th, 2001, 5:16:18 pm, and that we are in the
// Mountain Standard Time (MST) Time Zone

$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18

// and echo it out
echo $today;
?>
```

Hopes this helps.